# increase stem height of giant tcr advanced 2

Tags: road-bike, giant, modification

Is it possible to increase stem height of the Giant TCR advanced 2?  I want to make the bike less aggressive so I don't have to bend down so much don't care about being aero.

[image: From above website, stock photo]
https://www.giant-bicycles.com/us/tcr-advanced-2-pc

Comment: If you find the position uncomfortable it could also be a matter of saddle position. Could also just be that you have to get used to it (it does require some core muscles). If you are spending a lot of time on the “drop” position (lowest part) of the handlebars: Generally the idea is that you’d spend most of your time on the hoods and a considerable amount of time on the tops (the horizontal part close to the stem).

Comment: If you haven't bought the bike already, it most likely comes without the stem slammed like that.  It almost certainly comes with a longer steer tube and probably 5 cm or more of spacers between the stem and the frame.  And there are many road bike frames that have taller head tubes too, if you have other options.

Comment: Havent bought it yet just assuming its gonna be a pain since I'm used to hybrid bike.

Comment: @bakalolo: so prior to buying this or any other bike, get that bike fitting session. It is really well spent money. Especially so if you come from another kind cycling.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

1. Some stems can be flipped to give an upward angle instead of a downward one - this may be a zero-cost change for you.
2. You can replace the stem with one that has a higher angle.  Be aware that length and angle are interrelated, so changing only the angle will effectively shorten your reach too. 
   You might choose to buy an adjustable stem, and play with angles and lengths to find your personal optimal.  Then buy a solid stem of the specs you want, and retire/onsell the adjustable one.
3. Depending how long your fork's steerer tube is, there may be spacers you can relocate from above to below the stem.  This raises the bars and pulls them slightly back giving a shorter reach, so you may still need a longer stem.
    It is possible to put the saddle back slightly on its rails to allow for this.
4. Steerer tube extenders exist, but they're a bit rubbish.  Your steerer gets about 75mm taller, again effectively reducing reach.  And they look strange - I've fitted one to a bike and the handling changed enormously, not recommended.

Remember small changes can have large effects.  Don't go for big changes straight off, and try and get time on the bike with each set before modifying further.   Also, keep a record of what you changed so you can revert to a known point.

Comment: Possible, if not expensive, to install a new fork with a long steerer and use spacers.

Comment: Before making materiel changes invest some money in a bike fitting session.